# Поворот объекта

Tags: unity3d

Как поворачивать объект относительно своего края в Unity3D а не вокруг своего центра.

Comment: А что вы вращаете? 3d объект, спрайт или что-то в UI?

Answer (score -1):

Как вариант: создать пустой объект `EmptyObject`, поставить в его центр угол/сторону вашего объекта `YourObject` и сделать его дочерним для пустого. Таким образом, поворачивая `EmptyObject` вы будете поворачивать `YourObject` вокруг желаемой точки.